# Color code from name

Tags: ruby

In C#, you can get a color code from its name: `Color.FromName("Red")`.

Is there something similar in Ruby?

Comment: What sort of color code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ gem install color
$ irb
> require 'color/css'
> Color::CSS["blue"]
=> RGB [#0000ff] 
> Color::CSS["blue"].html
=> "#0000ff"
```

But that's not all!

```
> Color::CSS["blue"].pdf_fill
=> "0.000 0.000 1.000 rg" 
> Color::CSS["blue"].to_cmyk
=> CMYK [100.00%, 100.00%, 0.00%, 0.00%]
```